# How to deploy postgres on heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, heroku-postgres

I am working on a corona virus project based on nodejs and postgresql. I'm trying to deploy my app on heroku but i encounter some issues. Those issues comes from the the postgres configuration (i think).

I have a .env file where i've initialise some variables (DATABASE_URL,...) and i don't know how to transmit them to heroku.
I've associate an addon postgres-heroku and it generate a DATABASE_URL variable with a random value. And i want now, to set this value to my real DATABASE_URL in the .env file.

the commandes ---->   "heroku config:set DATABASE_URL= ****"   gives an issues...

The .env file

```
# DATABASE PARAMETERS

    DATABASE_NAME = *****
    DATABASE_USER = postgres
    DATABASE_PASSWORD = ********
    DATABASE_PORT = 5432
    DATABASE_HOST = localhost
    DATABASE_DIALECT = postgres
    DATABASE_HOST_PROD= 172.17.0.1
    
    export DATABASE_URL= postgres://postgres:*******@localhost:5432/*****
```

The database.yml file

```
# For dev 

   development:

# For prod
 
   production:

     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     database: ENV['DATABASE_NAME']
     pool: 5
     username: ENV['DATABASE_USER']
     url: ENV['DATABASE_URL']
     password: ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD']
     host: ENV['DATABASE_HOST']
```

The architecture:

```
 >config
 >models
 >node_modules
 >routes
 >services
 .env
 app.js
 database.yml
 package_lock.json
 package.json
 Procfile
```

Don't hesitate to ask for some code if needed.
I really really really, need your help guys...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break down DATABASE_URL so that you can add the variables you used for local.The format is like this

> database_driver:/username:password@host:port/database_name

Yyou cannot alter DATABASE_URL on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add those in `Config Vars` for your Project on Heroku.
Go to your project in Heroku > Settings > Reveal Config Vars

Add all the relevant production env variables there.